# Linear transformation with polynomial

Tags: linear-transformations

Determine if its linear the transformation

$f:\Re_{n}[x] \rightarrow \Re$

such as

$f(p(x))=p(x)+1$

for any $p(x) \in \Re_{n}$[x]

The solution says it's not linear but I worked it out like this:

Condition 1. $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$

$f(p(x))+p'(x))=((p(x)+1)+(p'(x)+1))=f(p(x))+f(p'(x))$

Condition 2. $\alpha T(u)=T(\alpha u)$

$\alpha f(p(x))= \alpha (p(x)+1) = \alpha p(x)+\alpha = f(\alpha p(x))$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a very careful look at the first equality of condition 1

Comment: Your fourth line contradicts your second one: the $\;f\;$ you're defining there is **not** a function to $\;\Bbb R\;$ (as written in second line) as it doesn't give a number (=a scalar), but a new polynomial. It also confusing what you wrote in the line below "condition 1", with derivatives and etc. Where does this all come from? So what **exactly** is the counter domain of $\;f\;$ and what exactly is the definition of $\;f\;$ ?

Comment: My notation was unfortunate, the p' is not the derivative

Comment: As for the $f: \Re_{n} [x] \rightarrow \Re$, I see what your saying. Maybe is a mistake in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be
$$f(p(x)+p'(x)) = p(x)+p'(x)+1 \ne p(x)+p'(x)+2 = f(p(x)) + f(p'(x))$$

Anyway, it is faster to note that $f(0) = 1 \ne 0$, so $f$ cannot be linear.